# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP with google app engine web projects

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Hi I am new to google app engine. After the initial created of the new google web application project, I attempt to create a simple `helloworld.jsp` page under the `/war` directory of the project. But i keep getting the following error, and not able to find out what is the problem:

```
An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:
Caused by:    
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
```

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

```
Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
```

I checked window -> preference -> java -> installed jre , and it is using `jdk1.8.0.91` and is checked. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: the error surfaced when i try to launch the page via http://localhost8888/helloworld.jsp

Comment: You'll have to provide the jsp file in order to help. There is no telling when we don't know your imports.

Comment: Have you found your way through this ?